# suggest unique random string generator in python??

Tags: python, random

Can any one please suggest me a unique random string generator in python.
 I have used **uuid.uuid1()**  before which is not good since it is showing some irregularities in different operating systems. You need to import uuid ahead of all the packages in a project for issue-less working which is not a good practice.
I have also heard about **os.urandom(n)** which uses /dev/random. Is its entropy **good enough** ?? I am not sure about that.
I can't afford a collision of strings in my process.
Is there any other method can help me in this ?

Comment: even if you achieved true randomness, it wouldn't prevent collisions.

Comment: is there any solution which has least chances of collisions ??

Comment: if you use a random generator, collisions are unlikely, but not impossible, so you have to take care of it. If you want truely unique numbers, then you may use a timestamp based number.

Comment: Dats what i am planning to do now... postpending timestamp with os.urandom(n) coz i read somewhere that in urandom after 4 billion iteration there is a chance of collision of 1 in 8 billion. Dats good enough for me.

Comment: What you read there about urandom is incomplete without the information how long the sample drawn out of urandom is.  `urandom` delivers an endless stream of bytes.  If your sample is just one byte long, then the chance to have a collision reaches 1 already at the 257th sample.

Answer (score 7):

What about the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) and [`string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) modules?

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> ''.join(random.sample(string.letters*5,5))
'QcQxx'
```

Explanation:

```
>>> string.letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

I multiply it by 5 so it can be even more random. The higher the number, the more duplicates you are more likely to obtain.

`random.sample(k, n)` returns `n` random elements from `string.letters`, but returns it as a list.

`''.join()` is called to join the list into a simple string.

Comment: I made an error upvoting, sorry. This solution won't repeat letters, and as such is not really random.

Comment: I've used `''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for i in range(DESIRED_LENGTH))`, which addresses @Agos's concern. Still no guarantees against duplicates, but a sufficiently long string should be sufficient for use around the house.

Comment: You can also use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` and then use the `random.choice()` to select from that. Or if you want to guarantee that a string never occurs twice (but at the cost of a bit of memory), you can do convert the generator from `combinations_with_replacement()` to a list, then use `random.shuffle()` to randomize the sequence and `pop()` off the strings one by one.

Comment: The solution in the answer does not scale.  Consider the case you want a 1GB long random letter string.  You'd create a 52GB long string for that first.  Also, by using `random.sample` in this way, the first letters influence the following.  For a combination of two letters, the chance for a double (two equal letters) should be ¹/₅₂; using this technique it is only ¹/₁₀₃.